# Routing with multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to add additional parameter in my route

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                  "CustomRoute",
                  "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}/{recid}",
                  new { action = "Index", id = "", recid = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );            

            routes.MapRoute(
              "Root",
              "",
              new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = "", recid = 

UrlParameter.Optional
);
```

The pages  with /controller/action/id are rendered correctly, but when i call page with /controller/action/id/recid i am not getting correct values in RouteData.Values in the following funcion. RouteData.Values has correct value initially. but after that function call itself again and RouteData.Values has three values rather than four and it has prompt.js in id field

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
            var RouteValue = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
            String p = RouteValue.ToString();
            this._DocumentID = String.IsNullOrEmpty(RouteValue["id"].ToString()) ? 2 : Convert.ToInt32(RouteValue["id"]);
            FormsIdentity ident = User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
            if (ident != null)
            { 
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = ident.Ticket;
                UserData = ticket.UserData;
                this._UserID = Convert.ToInt32(UserData.Split('|')[0]);
                this._RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(UserData.Split('|')[1]);
                this._EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(UserData.Split('|')[2]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you render contains a ressource prompt.js in it. Remove this file or change routing to ignore requests that end with .js.

Comment: But if i render the same page with {controller}.mvc/{action}/{id} and use the recid as query string parameter every thing works fine